# How to interpret survey data with demographic information?

Tags: categorical-data, survey, survey-weights

I have little statistical experience, but am helping to run a community needs survey for my organization. Many of the questions have a yes/no or multiple choice answer format. For example, "Do you have health insurance?" and if they aren't yes no, they are multiple choice "Why don't you have health insurance?" "1) Can't afford it 2) Don't know how to sign up 3) Not eligible due to immigration status"

We also collect demographic information: income, race, gender, county of residence, etc.

I am compiling a report on this data. I was initially planning to just present the responses to each question- 45% of people surveyed don't have health insurance. But of course- there is large and meaningful variability by demographics. I.e., 16/187 (8.5%) participants with household incomes greater than 60k don't have health insurance, while 48/223 (21.5%) participants with household incomes lower than 60k don't have health insurance. Is there anything I can do to further analyze this? Or do I report it just as I stated above?

All help is greatly appreciated. We are an underfunded nonprofit and hoping to use our data to write grants and develop new programs to help folks in the community!

Comment: Is it always the case that the multiple choice questions result from a yes/no answer ?

Comment: @caroz no, there are other multiple choice questions that don't result from a yes/no answer, for example "Due to the cost of prescription drugs, have you ever (select all that apply): 1) not filled a prescription 2) cut a prescription in half 3) skipped a dose 4) none of the above"

Comment: May I ask how many questions do you have in total ?

Comment: @caroz about 45, but there is logic in the survey so that not everyone is answering every question. Someone who stated they don't have health insurance wouldn't answer the question about where their health insurance is from, for example.

Comment: How has your sample been collected? Have you looked at census data for your community, and compared it to your sample data? You should give more details about your variables: how many respondents? 410? Are there a lot of non-respondents to some questions? How many counties are there? etc. In fact, your question is quite large in scope, you should focus it on some specific points. If you are simply exploring your dataset, then multiple correspondence analysis or multiple factor analysis *might* be interesting methods, but it's hard to say without more info about what you're looking for exactly.

Comment: @j-j-j Convienece sample, mostly from social media and events we host in state, partnerships with other local nonprofits, and outreach to past clients. 

The demographics skew more diverse and lower income than the state overall, which is what we were looking for. We primarily service vulnerable populations with free, direct services.

I don’t need to do anything too fancy. But it would be nice for maybe 5 of the more important questions if I could say something like, the data indicate that individuals with household incomes are less likely to have health insurance and back it up.

Comment: Then your population of interest is vulnerable people. If census data has information about this specific population (e.g. which % of women in the vulnerable population?), you could compare it to your sample, to see if there's some bias in your sample. That would be informative for future surveys, to know if you should change something about the collecting process. If your survey is online (partly or completely), it may have a bias against men and old people. If it is self-administered, it might have a bias against non-native speakers, illiterate people, and people with cognitive impairments.

Answer (score 0):

I will take the example of your first question "do you have health insurance ?" with "yes" or "no" being the response variables.
I would build a model (glm for binomial distribution) along the lines of
answer~ race + gender + income + county of residence
and then use the MuMIn package to see what variables receive the most support.

Then within the ones which do not have health insurance, I would use a multinomial logistic regression with the same model structure.
You can read more about these here :
https://www.r-bloggers.com/2020/05/multinomial-logistic-regression-with-r/
If you follow this link, go directly to "Setting the reference level". In your case "adi"   "car"   "con"   "other" would be "Can't afford it" "Don't know how to sign up" "Not eligible due to immigration status".

Maybe you would prefer this example here :
https://quantifyinghealth.com/multinomial-logistic-regression-in-r/

Of course if your first question already has more than 2 possible answers, you can directly use a multinomial logistic regression.

Apparently the MuMIn package works fine with multinomial regressions:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19465641/bad-compatibility-of-mumin-with-multinom-nnet-objects-having-3-level-response

The downside of this being that you will basically have one model per question, but I do not think you can avoid this.

Comment: With 410 respondents, enquiring about how the sample has been collected (e.g. is it a random sample?) and details about the variables (e.g. how many counties of residence are there? what percentage of non-responses? etc.) would be a good idea before suggesting glm and whatnot. The question as it stands is probably too vague or too large in scope.